# Dependency Walker Equivalent for 16 bit DLLs

Tags: dll, dependencies, 16-bit

I need to find the dependencies and functions of a 16 bit DLL file. I've found Dependency Walker and it looks immensely helpful, but it doesn't work on 16 bit DLLs. Does anyone know of a good alternative that will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [SCANBIN](http://www.bellamyjc.org/en/scanbin.html), looks like it does the job, and webpage comes straight from the 90's.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. You have to be on a system that will actually run those 16 bit DLLs to actually use it, though (I'm using a virtual Windows XP SP3, so not a problem). Now I just need to figure out the rest of the process of actually using those dependencies... :P